# camera and house picture problem

Tags: probability, statistics

There are many houses in a road but the number of houses is unknown. You have a camera that can only store the last taken picture. You sequently move from the first house to the last one and decide to take pictures with some probabilities. What is your strategy to ensure that every house has equal probability to appear in the saved picture?

Comment: What have you tried?  What chance you you assign to the first house?  the second? the third?  Does that give you a hint?

Comment: @Ems  I think the pattern will be obvious to you if you just look at what you do with the first few homes.  Clearly you take a picture of the first house, right?  Now you come to the second.  That might be the last one!  So, with what probability do you take a picture of that one? Does that answer give uniform probability for the first two homes? Now consider the third one.

Comment: @DonThousand:  If there is only one house, you lose unless you took its picture, so you take it with probability $1$.  Now if you find a second house, you want the chance that each of the two is in the camera to be $\frac 12$, so you take it with what probability?  Now if there is a third, you want each to be in the camera with probability $\frac 13$, so you take it...

Comment: @RossMillikan: I can't see anything in the question that precludes keeping the camera in your bag. Why do you lose if you take no pictures? (Perhaps, just to be on the safe side, you take a picture of your shoes first, just to guarantee zero probability for pictures of the houses.)